# JSP files won't compile - JSPTranslator.CouldNotLoadClass

Tags: jsp, configuration, java, jrun

I have 6 JSP applications running on a Windows Server 2003 box with JRun 4 with Updater 7 and the Java 1.6.0_14.  All of my applications are working just fine except for 1 of them and any new ones I create in JRun.  I just cannot find where the difference in configuration or permissions is.

Whenever I attempt to access a JSP file on the app that isn't working I get the following error.

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jrun__jsp__navigation__cm_doc2ejsp1a
at jrun.jsp.JSPClassLoader.findClass(JSPClassLoader.java:135)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
at jrun.jsp.JSPEngine.loadClass(JSPEngine.java:657)
at jrun.jsp.JSPEngine.loadClass(JSPEngine.java:646)
at jrun.jsp.JSPEngine.loadServlet(JSPEngine.java:874)
at jrun.jsp.JSPEngine.getServlet(JSPEngine.java:728)
at jrun.jsp.JSPServlet.service(JSPServlet.java:115)
at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)

 javax.servlet.ServletException: JSPTranslator.CouldNotLoadClass/jsp/navigation/cm_doc.jsp
at jrun.jsp.JSPEngine.loadServlet(JSPEngine.java:880)
at jrun.jsp.JSPEngine.getServlet(JSPEngine.java:728)
at jrun.jsp.JSPServlet.service(JSPServlet.java:115)
at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
```

I understand that the error means that the JSP file could not be compiled into the WEB-INF/jsp folder, but I cannot figure out why.  All the other sites are working fine.  Also, have the same issue for any new JRun applications I create while trying to debug this. We had recently updated the JVM from 1.4.2.18 to 1.6.0.14, but it wasn't *that* recent, and the fact that the other sites are working baffles me.  I don't know, I'm at a loss.  I'll post my jrun-web.xml file for completeness, and if any specific logs that might help, just let me know.  Thanks for any help or suggestions you can provide.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jrun-web-app PUBLIC "-//Macromedia, Inc.//DTD jrun-web 4.0//EN" "http://jrun.macromedia.com/dtds/jrun-web.dtd">
<jrun-web-app>
  <session-config>
    <persistence-config>
      <active>true</active>
    </persistence-config>
    <replication-config>
      <active>false</active>
    </replication-config>
  </session-config>
  <context-root>/</context-root>
  <compile>false</compile>
  <reload>false</reload>
  <uri-character-encoding>UTF-8</uri-character-encoding>
  <virtual-mapping>
    <resource-path>/*</resource-path>
    <system-path>D:\WebApps\RegAbbrev\</system-path>
  </virtual-mapping>
  <enable-jrun-web-services>true</enable-jrun-web-services>
  <virtual-mapping>
    <resource-path>/</resource-path>
    <system-path />
  </virtual-mapping>
</jrun-web-app>
```

Comment: How did you get Jrun to work under Java6? I've never gotten it to boot if I point it at a Java6 JRE.

Comment: Urgh. Do you really need to keep using JRun?  It's just awful.

Comment: @skaffman, he is not the only one stuck on it. I spent 4 hours or so today dealing with issues caused by Jrun. Great use of my time.

Comment: Can you clarify, "All of my applications are working just fine except for 1 of them and any new ones I create in JRun."?

Comment: @nemo we actually had to install the JDK instead of just the JRE to get it to run under Java6.  Completely baffling, but we had a security requirement to be at that version, and one attempt at getting it to work, we installed the JDK instead and the applications worked.

Comment: @nemo "All of my applications..." - basically five of my six server/applications have no errors being raised.  One server/application will not serve a JSP without throwing the above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem somehow ended up being the actual code files or the directory they were housed in.  I have no idea as to what could have happened to the files since it was every JSP page and not just ones that may have gotten corrupted somehow.  But I took another copy of the app's most recent release, put it into a new folder, pointed both IIS and JRun to it, and bamn, it works.  Still baffled.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend stopping Jrun and clearing out the **{*ServerInstance*}/Server-Inf/temp** directory.

The temp directory is the source of many problems with Jrun as it often doesn't clear the temp files out properly.

Comment: Yeah, tried that.  But also there's the fact that new servers and applications aren't working either, so that kinda also eliminates that the temp dir is the problem